# Else is not working in my payment check program C#

Tags: c#, database, if-statement

There are only 3 situations for result.
1- Paid
2- waiting for payment
3- blocked
(Think like this is a bank program)

So when I run the code, always says true. Never false. I want it work normally. Need help.

```
[HttpPut(Name = "OdemeYapildiSosyalOdeme")]
        public ActionResult<bool> Put(string tckn, int odemeNo)
        {
            try
            {
              

                DbOperations dbOperations = new DbOperations();

                var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
                var param1 = new SqlParameter("TCKN", tckn);
                parameters.Add(param1);

                var param2 = new SqlParameter("ODEMENO", odemeNo);
                parameters.Add(param2);


                if (odemeKd == 0)
                {

                    dbOperations.ExecuteNonQuery("ODEME_YAP", parameters);

                    return Ok(true);
                }

                else return Ok(false);












using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using SosyalYardimApi.Operations;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace SosyalYardimApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SosyalOdemeController : ControllerBase
    {
        private int odemeKd;
        private object sosyalOdemeleri;

        public bool Boolean { get; private set; }

        [HttpGet(Name = "SorgulaSosyalOdeme ")]
        public ActionResult<List<SosyalOdeme>> Get(string tckn)
        {
            try
            {
                //Yapılacak: Tckn 11 karakterli mi kontrolü yapılacak değilse dönüş olacak,
                //return Ok("TCKN Hatalı");
                if (tckn.Length == 11)
                {
                    List<SosyalOdeme> sosyalOdemeleri = new List<SosyalOdeme>();

                    DbOperations dbOperations = new DbOperations();

                    var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
                    var param = new SqlParameter("TCKN", tckn);
                    parameters.Add(param);
                    DataTable dtSonuc = dbOperations.GetData("MUSTERI_SELECT", parameters);


                    for (int i = 0; i < dtSonuc.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        SosyalOdeme sosyalOdeme = new SosyalOdeme();

                        sosyalOdeme.OdemeNo = Convert.ToInt32(dtSonuc.Rows[i]["ODEMENO"]);
                        sosyalOdeme.Tckn = Convert.ToString(dtSonuc.Rows[i]["TCKIMLIKNO"]);
                        sosyalOdeme.Adi = dtSonuc.Rows[i]["MUSTERIAD"].ToString();
                        sosyalOdeme.SoyAdi = dtSonuc.Rows[i]["MUSTERISOYAD"].ToString();
                        sosyalOdeme.OdemeKd = Convert.ToInt32(dtSonuc.Rows[i]["ODEME_KD"]);
                        sosyalOdeme.OdenecekTtr = Convert.ToDecimal(dtSonuc.Rows[i]["ODENECEK_TTR"]);
                        if (dtSonuc.Rows[i]["ODEME_TR"] != DBNull.Value)
                            sosyalOdeme.OdenecekDt = Convert.ToDateTime(dtSonuc.Rows[i]["ODEME_TR"]);

                        sosyalOdemeleri.Add(sosyalOdeme);
                    }

                    return Ok(sosyalOdemeleri);
                }
                else return Ok("hatalı tckn girdiniz");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }



        [HttpPut(Name = "OdemeYapildiSosyalOdeme")]
        public ActionResult<bool> Put(string tckn, int odemeNo)
        {
            try
            {
                
                    //Yapılacak: Odeme no ve tckn e ait ödemeyi bul
                    //Ödemenin durum kontrolü yap  =0 ise 
                    //eğer kontrolden başarılı geçmez ise false dön işlemi kes

                    DbOperations dbOperations = new DbOperations();

                    var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();
                    var param1 = new SqlParameter("TCKN", tckn);
                    parameters.Add(param1);

                    var param2 = new SqlParameter("ODEMENO", odemeNo);
                    parameters.Add(param2);

                  
                if (odemeKd == 0)
                {
                    dbOperations.ExecuteNonQuery("ODEME_YAP", parameters);

                    return Ok(true);
                }
                else return Ok(false);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So that's the whole code for odemeKd.

We have one more big code but there is no definition in the other one.

So i hope you can find the answer of this code.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Shared code does not have definition for `odemeKd` so it is hard to say why it should not be equal to 0.

Comment: So, after that is it going to work for sure? I can't try it at the moment because i'm at mobile right now.
edit: Also this is not whole code, i could take only one part. I think if it didn't have definition, we couldn't see the "True" as answer, no?

Comment: _" Also this is not whole code, i could take only one part"_ -  I have no doubts in this)  _"if it didn't have definition, we couldn't see the "True" as answer, no? "_ - if it had no definition you would not be able to see any answer cause code would not compiled.

Comment: So sir, that code giving us answer as "True". Then we have another problem. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You have misunderstood my first comment. It does not say that the problem is the absence of the definition for `odemeKd`. It says that without definition for `odemeKd` we can't help you.

Comment: Now i edit my first entry. You can see everything in the end. Thank you so much.

Comment: `SosyalOdemeController.odemeKd` is private field which is never updated, so it will always contain the default value - 0 for `int`.